# SpringIntegration Cron trigger

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Hi I am using SpringIntegration with the trigger to poll the directory. So far the things are all good.

But I am having issue at the poller start and end time are like 12:05pm and 18:15pm

```
0 0/1 12-18 ? * MON-FRI
```

Above works fine every minute between 12 and 18 but I cannot find a way to set the time as well

Is that supported

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow inboundFileIntegration(

    ) {
        CronTrigger cronTrigger = new CronTrigger("0 0/1 12-18 ? * MON-FRI");


        return IntegrationFlows.from(fileReadingMessageSource(),
                c -> c.poller(Pollers.trigger(cronTrigger)
                        .maxMessagesPerPoll(10).advice(new AbstractMessageSourceAdvice() {
                            @Override
                            public Message<?> afterReceive(Message<?> message, MessageSource<?> messageSource) {
                                System.out.println("after");
                                return message;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean beforeReceive(MessageSource<?> source) {
                                System.out.println("before");
                                return true;
                            }
                        })))
//                        .transactionSynchronizationFactory(transactionSynchronizationFactory())
//                        .transactional(transactionManager())))
                .log()
                .transform(Files.toStringTransformer())
                .transform(o -> {
//                    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("testing_queue", o);
                    System.out.println(o);
                    return o;
                })


                .channel(ApplicationConfiguration.INBOUND_CHANNEL)
                .get();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may set minutes they same way you set hours:

```
0 15-35 12-17 1/1 * ? MON-FRI
```